# Trying to select distinct on my dropdownlist

Tags: c#, forms, drop-down-menu

[image: Tables]

I have this table called FACILITIES. I am trying to have only one unique data in the FAC_TYPE field. In my data i have two meeting data. I only want to have one meeting data display inside only. I tried putting distinct in my code but it doesn't work. howwwww?

```
   using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class MainMenu : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnectionString"].ToString(); // connection string
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct FAC_CODE, FAC_TYPE from FACILITIES", con);  
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);  // fill dataset

            ddlMedicalCentre.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_TYPE"].ToString(); // text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FAC_CODE"].ToString();             // to retrive specific  textfield name 
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];      //assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
            ddlMedicalCentre.DataBind();  //binding dropdownlist
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why it happening is because you might have  different code but same name if you want distinct by name use

```
"select distinct FAC_TYPE,  FAC_CODE, from FACILITIES"
```

Comment: I don't understand u said about the different code but same name. And the code u gave have a comma in front of FAC_CODE and it gave me Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from' @COLD TOLD

Comment: distinct is different